# How can I execute DoCmd.RunSQL without confirmation dialog boxes?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been working on an inventory system using MS Access, everything is going well. I just want to ask if there is a way to execute `DoCmd.RunSQL` without these prompts/dialog boxes?

[image]

Comment: Hi everyone, I have solved this by putting single and double quotes. :) thank  you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Replace, after having set `YourParameterValue` to a value that makes sense:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL Replace(YourSqlString, "Purchased_4/1/2019", YourParameterValue)
```

or, if the value is a string:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL Replace(YourSqlString, "Purchased_4/1/2019", "'" & YourParameterValue & "'")
```

Though that parameter name seems a bit weird ...

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL` doesn't take parameters from `DoCmd.SetParameter`.`DoCmd.OpenQuery` does though.

Comment: @ErikA: You are right. Thanks. I've edited the answer.